# Java Double array with null values to R variable

Tags: java, r, nuiton

I'm using the nuiton library for Java to R connections. I'm trying to assign a Double[] array to an R variable, but it will only allow this with primitive doubles. Is this because of the library or is there another way I should pass empty values to R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nuiton-j2r is built to send String instructions to R (on a local instance or a R server). So to assign a Double[] array to an R variable, I build a String that does the assignation (myArray is the Double array end engine my REngine) :

```
StringBuilder myBuilder = new StringBuilder();

myBuilder.append("myVariable<-c(");

for (Double dble:myArray) {
    myBuilder.append(dble.toString());
    myBuilder.append(",");
}

myBuilder.deleteCharAt(myBuilder.length()-1);

myBuilder.append(")");

engine.eval(myBuilder.toString());
```

Now on your R session you got your Double array.

To get it back Java side once dealt with on R side, you can do :

```
Double[] arrayCopy = (Double[])engine.eval(myVariable);
```

(Note : I did not try this, only by memory, maybe some tweaking needed)

Comment: And for null values, I think you cannot pass them with nuiton-j2r (my code is not null-proof here) as R does not recognize null

Comment: I came to that same solution after a while. I didn't realize at first that it literally expected you to make a string as if in the commandline.